# c++: change font of a simple output program

Tags: c++, fonts

I noticed that in command prompt you are able to change the properties so that it displays text in a different font. How might you set a program so that it automatically uses the font chosen?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

}
```

How might you change the Hello World program so that it displays the text in a different font? also, please keep in mind that if the program opens with the font type set the font should be included in the program and not linked to a font that is already installed on the computer. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think a font-changing mechanism should do if I start the program with `program.exe >file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without changing the font for your terminal emulator. cout writes the text you give it to a thing called "standard out" (stdout) which only contains text. It doesn't contain any information about fonts.

Whatever is displaying the output of your program is reading that text, then displaying it to you with some font that it has decided to use, so, the program can't control it.

This is similar to how you can't change the font in a plain text file. The text editor decides how to display the text, and the file only contains text.